# CDF beyond range of values in R ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, cdf, ecdf

I am trying to plot the CDF using ggplot2 in R and I get the following plot[image]

But the min and max values of the data are 1947 and 2017. I do not want the line to be plot beyond the ranges [1947, 2017].

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=year)) + stat_ecdf(geom="line") + xlab("Year") + xlim(1947, 2017)
```

Can anyone help with this issue?

Comment: Have you tried `xlim(1947,2017)` or something similar?

Comment: i tried it but it gives me the same result - I updated the code above

Comment: Ok, you probably want the `expand` argument in `scale_x_continuous` then. Start with setting it to `c(0,0)` and then tinker until you get what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the pad parameter with FALSE value:

```
ggplot( data.frame(x=1947:2017), aes(x=x)) + stat_ecdf(geom="line", pad=FALSE)
```

[image]